# Defined background color in Eclipse doesn't match emulator

Tags: android

I defined a shape with the following tag to define the background color:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#64B4E5" />
    <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="#C9C9C9" />

</shape>
```

The color shows up fine in eclipse but when I run it in the emulator, the color does not match at all; it shows up as green.

Any idea why?

In Eclipse:
[image: In Eclipse:]

In Emulator: 
[image: In E]

Comment: Because no two display devices display a color the same way, unless they're calibrated. The difference between teal and green can hardly be classified as not matching "at all."

Comment: Actually it's dramatically different. Edited the post to show what they look.

Comment: I have checked and tried your code its working perfect in my emulator.

Comment: @GrIsHu When you tried it out in your emulator, it looks like my Eclipse picture? I even tried it on my phone and the color still doesn't match.

Comment: No it looks like same as in Graphical layout layout no color change. It may happening because of the device color themes which android have. Different android devices have different ways to identify the colors.

Answer (score 0):

```
   android:background="#64B4E5" <-- try this
```

Comment: I can't apply that attribute to shape.